# How do I delete padding in CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, padding

I have used CSS below to remove the title and some padding but there is still padding that I can't seem to remove.

This is my current coding:

```
    .site-info { display: none; }
header.entry-header {
    display: none;
}
.page .post-header {
    display: none;
}
```

On Inspect it states

```
<div id="content" class="site-content" style="padding-top: 2.5em;
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

The padding is being inherited from somewhere else. Either default browser settings, or one of your other divs/elements. You can use the id of the div, or the class, in CSS to manually change it like so:

```
#content, .site-content {
 padding-top: 0px;
}
```

You can try just using the id tag or the class tag to see which one specifically is causing the padding inheritance. Would have to see more code/the site to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

The padding is being set somewhere else `content` is a common id tag in a stylesheet- you can override it.

```
<style>
 body #content{
   padding:0px;
 }
</style>
```

if that doesn't work, this will

```
<style>
 body #content{
   padding:0px !important;
 }
</style>
```

Comment: What would this be in CSS code? I tried copying and pasting that to CSS and nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="content" class="site-content" style="padding-top: 2.5em;
```

Aren't you getting paddimg from here? The inline style. Inline elements have higher order than internal or external css